# Use python to implement a async notification system

Tags: python, notifications, cron

I have been troubled by a design question.

I want to implement a small service that looks like a **mail office**. It will accept clients request(in the request it has the **message** to deliver and **destination url** info). After that I will help the client to send the message to specified URL. BUT when the first trial fails(I expect a 200 with 'success' response) there is some strategy like I will continually send the message to the destination url **at most** 10 times. And I will wait for a certain time to send the message again. For example, I send the message immediately after I receive the request(the following looks like a delivery algorithm):

```
if it fails then 
   I will wait for 1 minutes to send it again 
if it fails again then 
   I will wait for a longer time period(like 5 minutes) and so on
until the num of trials reaches Max(10 times).
```

I used to use django framework with django-cron to solve the problem. However it is not accurate for it depends on the time I set for the django-cron(the less time between the cron the better). I don't know whether there is an elegant and appropriate method to solve this kind of problem.

Thank you for your help!